# Laravel Events with Bus::batch

Tags: laravel, events

I'm doing a Bus::batch with Laravel 8.*

I have the next code:

```
$batch = Bus::batch([
      new ProcessEmailsEvent($email),
    ])->then(function (Batch $batch) use ($email) {
      $email->update([
        'status' => 'completed',
      ]);
    })->catch(function (Batch $batch, Throwable $e) use ($email) {
      $email->update([
        'status' => 'failed',
      ]);
    })->onQueue('emails')->dispatch();
```

Then, I use the trait `Batchable` in `ProcessEmailsEvent`

But when the event process, it fails because:

```
Error: Call to undefined method App\Events\ProcessEmailsEvent::__invoke()
```

The class of ProcessEmailsEvent is:

```
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels, Batchable;

  public $emailExcel;

  /**
   * Create a new event instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(EmailExcel $emailExcel)
  {
    $this->emailExcel = $emailExcel;
  }
```

What I'm doing wrong? it need a special method __invoke()? why?

or batch just work with jobs?

Update:
If I created a "__invoke()" method on event, it doesn't dispatch events and listeners.

Update2:
If I change "event" to "job", it works correctly. Exist any way to run it with Events?

thanks!

Comment: Does your ProcessEmailsEvent implements ShouldQueue?

Comment: @Nothingbutageek Yes. I try with ShouldQueue in Event, also in Listeners. But error of undefined method "__invoke()" always show.

Answer (score 0):

add this method in your event class:

```
public function __invoke(YourClassListener $listener)
{
    $listener->handle($this);
}
```